# Sorting a linkedlist only works with redundant iterator

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote the code to sort a LinkedList for a school assignment. It works, sort of, but it doesn't run enough times. So I added a third for loop and now it works, but I don't understand why it only works with the third iterator. Could someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? And how I should be doing it? This was feels wrong and can barely handle linked lists larger than 1000.

```
    public void sort() {
    Node min;
    for (Node shouldNotNeedThis = head; shouldNotNeedThis != null; shouldNotNeedThis = shouldNotNeedThis.next) {
        for (Node ix = shouldNotNeedThis.next; ix != null; ix = ix.next) {
            min = ix;
            for (Node tx = ix.next; tx != null; tx = tx.next) {
                if (tx.compareTo(min) == -1) {
                    min = tx;
                }
            }
            if (min != ix) {
                swapNodes(ix, min);
                ix = min;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void swapNodes(Node currentNode, Node nextNode) {
    Integer temp = currentNode.data;
    currentNode.data = nextNode.data;
    nextNode.data = temp;
}
```

Comment: One general comment: compareTo is not required to return -1; it can return anything < 0.

Comment: I wrote the compareTo method, and it only returns either -1, 0, or 1

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but there are many classes in Java that have a compareTo method and the usual convention is that we compare the result of compareTo with 0, rather than comparing for equality with specific values. In your case it works, but you may find some other class in the future where it doesn't.

Comment: btw what to you mean by "it doesn't run enough times?"

Comment: Its as if it only went through the list once. So most of the smallest values move towards the top of the list, but not all the way. Running it again moves them closer. Run it again, and they move closer yet again.

Comment: Edit: crap, theres no formatting in comments...

I added a print statement right after the closing bracket of the second for loop and this was the output
[40163]  
[103519]  
[162857]  
[173015]  
[55915]  

[40163]  
[55915]  
[162857]  
[173015]  
[103519]  

[40163]  
[55915]  
[103519]  
[173015]  
[162857]  

[40163]  
[55915]  
[103519]  
[162857]  
[173015]  

[40163]  
[55915]  
[103519]  
[162857]  
[173015]  

[40163]  
[55915]  
[103519]  
[162857]  
[173015]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
        if (min != ix) {
            swapNodes(ix, min);
            ix = min;
        }
```

It is sufficient to just swap the nodes. By setting ix to min, you are setting it to some arbitrary value somewhere in the middle of the rest of the list, which once held the minimum value (but doesn't any more). Unfortunately, ix is the variable you are using to iterate through your list. So each time you set ix, you are skipping a few elements.